# Problema al compilar Xamarin en Celular

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

Resulta que estaba haciendo 2 ejercicios con Xamarin muy sencillos, el primero me compiló muy bien y todo y funcionó a la perfección, sin embargo el segundo funciona bien en la laptop pero a la hora de tratar correrlo en el celular me arroja los siguientes errores:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Botón_Suma
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int count = 0;
        void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            count++;
            ((Button)sender).Text = $"Haz hecho click {count} veces.";
        }
    }
}
```

Me da error cuando intento pegarlo, es este:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Botón_Suma.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="24" CornerRadius="0">
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="36"/>
        </Frame>
        <Button Text="Dame Click" Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

¿Qué puedo hacer? Agradecería mucho su ayuda

Comment: Que estas haciendo?. Agrega el còdigo de lo que realizas

Comment: @Jorgesys Listo amigo, disculpa, como en la laptop no me arroja ningún error del código creí que no sería necesario pero allí está, gracias por tu sugerencia

Comment: sera la tilde de botón?

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar el xml del layout donde tienes tus botones y demases?

Comment: Me da error cuando intento pegarlo, es este <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Botón_Suma.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="24" CornerRadius="0">
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="36"/>
        </Frame>
        <Button Text="Dame Click" Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>

Comment: @gbianchi al parecer era eso, ¡gracias amigo!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

el error

> el sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado

en inglés:

> The system cannot find the file specified.

Es un problema entre [otras causas](https://vicenteguzman.mx/2018/05/21/error-unable-to-start-debugging-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-xamarin-forms-xamarin-android/) como en este caso en el cual alguna ruta de archivo, nombre de clase tiene caracteres que no son del idioma inglés y que son acentuados los cuales se deben evitar.

```
namespace Botón_Suma
{
   ...
   ...
}
```

debería ser:

```
namespace Boton_Suma
{
   ...
   ...
}
```

Revisa:

[**Error (failed to open directory: the system cannot find the file specified) when using Xamarin Android**](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/error-failed-to-open-directory-the-system-cannot-f/745431)